# Vue3/TypeScript - Can not import interface bc. of missing export default?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wrote an interface that I want to use in my component. However, it seems like I can't really import the interface and I can't see the reason why.

Here's the important code:

My interface in src/types/Job.ts

```
interface Job {
  name: string,
  salary: string,
  isPopular: boolean
}

export default Job
```

And my App.vue setup function & import:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import Job from './types/Job'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const jobs = ref<Job[]>([
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ])

    return { jobs }
  }
})
```

As an error I am getting the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/Job.ts' does not provide an export named 'default' (at App.vue:55:8)
```

And I really wonder why or what is missing. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Try out `import type Job from './types/Job'`

Comment: Oh that worked, thanks! I was following a youtube tutorial that haven't added the "type" before in the import and it worked there. Really confusing but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to add `type` after the import keyword :

```js
import type Job from './types/Job'
```